# How to Prepare for Informatics Olympiad and ACM-ICPC?

Tags: reference-request, books, programming-contest

As a beginner to competitive programming, I want to know a few things about informatics Olympiad such as the resources and books needed to prepare for the competition. I also want to know which problems should I solve from CodeChef, HackerRank, etc because I was unable to find Olympiad problems and most of the problems are not accessible for free.

**Note**- I have only started learning the algorithm book by CLRS but the questions do not have solutions for most of the time, so please provide the reference of the solution manual for the problems.

Comment: Please someone answer my question. I have tried to find tons of resources but was unable to prepare for th Olympiad. I am completely new to the websites so please guide me in this regard.

Comment: https://ioinformatics.org/page/contests/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a good starting point is the following list compiled by Codechef:
https://www.codechef.com/certification/data-structures-and-algorithms/prepare

It contains resources and problems for all relevant topics.

It's also important to participate in competitions along the way - you can check both Codeforces and Codechef for that

Comment: Can you specifically tell me the contests , as I am unable to find them . The contests which I click for says ‘this is not available for mobile browser’, and something like that. So please could you specify some contests. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: I think you can see all future contests (from various sites etc) here https://competitiveprogramming.info/calendar
I would start by trying the Div3 and Div2 contests from codeforces.
You can also see those here: https://codeforces.com/calendar